# Refrescar activity/ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo una `ExpandableListView` que le paso unos `Strings` de una base de datos, hasta aquí genial. Al cargar el Activity no me aparece el `ExpandableListView` con sus items.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si pongo un `EditText`y le doy click, de golpe me aparece la lista.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a refrescar la pantalla  con un `finish();`y`startActivity(intent);` pero deja de funcionar. No sé si es que el EditText tiene un `Listener` que va refrescando cuando se le hace click pero mi objetivo es lograr que cargue al iniciar el `Activity`.

Comment: Hola Alex, edita un poco tu pregunta agregando lo que llevas de código, te recomiendo leer [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Muchas gracias!!